i am trying to Run my code on PKU-MMD dataset but they give me this error
File "/public/usman/SCD-NET/feeder/augmentations.py", line 135, in temporal_cropresize
temporal_context=temporal_context.permute(0, 2, 3, 1).contiguous().view(C * V * M,temporal_crop_length)
RuntimeError: shape '[150, 336]' is invalid for input of size 43200
I am facing that issue when i run NTU datasets they work properly but when we go through PKU-MMD they will create this problem
